# Rails 3. how to use disable_with in button tag?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently started testing web_app_theme plugin. In Create button I have something like this...

```
<button class="button" type="submit">
  <%= image_tag("web-app-theme/icons/tick.png", :alt => "#{t("web-app-theme.save", :default => "Save")}") %> <%= t("web-app-theme.save", :default => "Save") %>
</button>
```

How can I add `:disable_with => "Processing"` to this button to prevent duplicate records?

I tried `t("web-app-theme.save", :default => "Save"), :disable_with => "Processing"`, but of course, that didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use form tag helper methods - something like this should do it:

```
<%= button_tag :class => "button", :type => "submit", :data => { :disable_with => "Processing" } do %>
  <%= image_tag("web-app-theme/icons/tick.png", :alt => "#{t("web-app-theme.save", :default => "Save")}") %> 
  <%= t("web-app-theme.save", :default => "Save") %>
<% end %>
```

Here's a link to the API docs for the `button_to` method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Updated Dec 14, 2013 for Rails 3.2 & 4 syntax.

Comment: thanks! just one edit: there shouldn't be a comma right after button_tag. i tried editing but it tells me that I have to edit at least 6 charaacters

Comment: Ah - yeah, thanks for catching that. I was just typing away frantically!

Comment: Is this going to be deprecated?

Comment: It's not deprecated, but the old implementation was - I've updated the answer to include the new syntax. It's an easy update, just put actions like `:disable_with` or `:confirm` inside of a `:data` hash.

Answer (score 5):

button_tag is entirely optional.  You could just as easily edit the tag in html as follows:

```
<button class="button" type="submit" data-disable-with="Processing">
  <%= image_tag("web-app-theme/icons/tick.png", :alt => "#{t("web-app-theme.save", :default => "Save")}") %> <%= t("web-app-theme.save", :default => "Save") %>
</button>
```

All that `:disable_with` does is add a data-disable-with attribute to the element.  Then the jquery-rails gem's javascript (jquery_ujs.js) does the rest of the disabling work for you.

This is assuming, of course, that you're on rails 3.0 or higher.

Comment: Can I specify the value to show after the ajax processing is done, instead of resetting to value prior to ajax?

Comment: @Dean not without your own javascript that sets the text as you want.  When you say 'ajax processing' does that mean you're using `data-remote=true`?  You should be able to do something like `$('button[type=submit]').on('ajax:success', function(e){$(this).val("New Text")})`